# Can't display hover with pseudo-element

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a project for my studies which is to display data on a dashboard that will be more or less modifiable by the user according to his needs.

In a pop up, I have tried to add shadows when moving the cursor over images via pseudo-elements but they do not appear. I would like some advice on where my error could be coming from?

Here is the html and css code:

```js
const body = document.querySelector("body"),
    sidebar = body.querySelector(".sidebar"),
    btn = body.querySelector("#btn");

    btn.addEventListener("click", () =>{
        sidebar.classList.toggle("active");
    })

const modalContainer = document.querySelector(".modal-container");
const modalTriggers = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-trigger");
modalTriggers.forEach(trigger => trigger.addEventListener("click",toggleModal))

function toggleModal(){
    modalContainer.classList.toggle("active")
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

*{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

:root{
    /* ===== Colors ===== */
    --body-color: #E4E9F7;
    --sidebar-color: #FFF;
    --primary-color: #1c1a1a;
    --primary-color-light: #F6F5FF;
    --toggle-color: #DDD;
    --text-color: #707070;

    /* ===== Transition ===== */
    --tran-02: all 0.2s ease;
    --tran-03: all 0.3s ease;
    --tran-04: all 0.4s ease;
    --tran-05: all 0.5s ease;
}

body{
    height: 100vh;
    background: var(--body-color);
}

/*Paramètres de la sidebar*/
.sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height:100%;
    width: 78px;
    background: var(--primary-color);
    padding: 6px 14px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

/*Activer l'élargissement de la sidebar*/
.sidebar.active{
    width: 240px
}

/*Paramètre du logo*/
.sidebar .logo_content .logo{
    color: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    width:100%;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

/*Activation de l'affichage du logo*/
.sidebar.active .logo_content .logo{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
}

/*?*/
.logo_content .logo i{
   font-size: 28px;
   margin-right: 5px;
}

/*Paramètre texte logo*/
.logo_content .logo .logo_name{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

/*Paramètre du bouton d'activation de la sidebar*/
.sidebar #btn{
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFF;
    top: 6px;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

/*Activer le déplacement du bouton en mode toggle*/
.sidebar.active #btn{
    left:90%;
}
/*Paramètre de la liste*/
.sidebar ul{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/*Paramètres pour chaque éléments de la liste*/
.sidebar li{
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height:50px ;
}

/*Paramètres des textes de chaque élément*/
.sidebar li a{
    color: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    border-radius: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/*Activer un fond par dessus lors du passage de la souris*/
.sidebar li a:hover{
    color: #11101d;
    background: #FFF;
}

/*Paramètres des logos*/
.sidebar li a i{
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*Désactiver l'affichage des noms*/
.sidebar .links_name{
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

/*Activer l'affichage des noms*/
.sidebar.active .links_name{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

/*Séparation des 2 sous menus*/
.sidebar .menu-bar{
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

/*Paramètres de la page des templates*/
.home{
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 78px;
    width: calc(100% - 78px);
    background: var(--body-color);
    transition: var(--tran-05);
}

/*Paramètre texte de la page*/
.home .text{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--text-color);
    padding: 8px 40px;
}

/*Activer le mouvement de la page*/
.sidebar.active ~ .home{
    left: 240px;
    width: calc(100% - 78px);
}

/*Paramètres de la fenêtre modal*/
.modal-container{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/*Activer la fenêtre modale lors de l'appui sur le bouton template*/
.modal-container.active{
    display: flex;
}

/*Paramètres de l'overlay lorsque la fenêtre modal est ouverte*/
.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333333d3;
}

.template{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    height: 300px;
    max-height: 720px;
    min-width: 520px;
    width: 45%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/**/
.popup-header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 8.5%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0% 2%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/*Paramètre du bouton de la fenêtre modal*/
.close-modal{
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #fff;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/*Activation du background lors du passage de la souris*/
.close-modal:hover{
    color: #FFF;
    background: rgb(188, 15, 15);
}

/*Paramètres du texte de la modal*/
.popup-header h1{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.popup-body{
    height: 80%;
    padding: 2%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.modal-container .popup-body ul{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 10px;
    list-style: none;
    column-width: 200px;
}

.modal-container .popup-body ul li a img{
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 175px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(18,18,18,0.5);
}

.modal-container .popup-body ul li a img::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(18,18,18,0.8);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
    z-index: 1;
}

.modal-container .popup-body ul li a img:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'"> -->
    
    <!----===== CSS ===== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!----===== Boxicons CSS ===== -->
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <title>Sail Vision</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="logo_content">
          <div class="logo">
            <i class='bx bx1-c-plus-plus'></i>
            <div class="logo_name">SailVision</div>
          </div>
          <i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-bar">
          <ul class="dash_list">
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class='bx bx-windows'></i>
                <span class="links_name">Dashboard n°1</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class='bx bx-windows'></i>
                <span class="links_name">Dashboard n°2</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class='bx bx-windows'></i>
                <span class="links_name">Dashboard n°3</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class='bx bx-customize modal-trigger'></i>
                <span class="links_name">Template</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="bottom_content">
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  <i class='bx bx-cog'></i>
                  <span class="links_name">Paramètre</span>
                </a>
              </li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="home">
        <div class="template-1">Template n°1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-container">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="template">
            <div class="popup-header">
              <button class="close-modal modal-trigger">X</button>
              <h1>Choix des templates</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="popup-body">
              <ul class="temp-list">
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="Template1.png" alt="t1">
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="Template1.png" alt="t1">
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="Template1.png" alt="t1">
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Regards

Comment: Please add a snippet to your question which can reproduce the issue by the click of a button.

Comment: I add a snippet but i use a local image in the modal window.

Comment: Thank you! How should I open the popup?

Comment: The pop up is opened by pressing the fifth icon from the top.

Comment: The fifth icon is not appearing for me if I run the code snippet (I'm using a small screen). Are the other icons necessary for this snippet?

Comment: You need to use the full page to see the fifth icon. And the other icons are not really necessary for this snippet.

Comment: Can you edit your snippet and remove the elements that are not necessary for this question?

Comment: On further research, I found the following link: https://weekendprojects.dev/posts/css-after-not-working/. So the problem was that i can't use pseudo-elements with replaced elements like image.